# Условия эксплуатации ПО

Tags: безопасность

Нужен ваш совет. ВОТ есть расширенный "диспетчер задач"... гуглил, читал. Но так и не понял, что можно написать в разделе Условия эксплуатации и надежность программы? Как его там можно распарсить?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

[@Tim](/users/3288/tim), Вы же понимаете каков вопрос (не Ваш, а в курсовой или что там...), таков ответ. Напишите:

```
Особых требований к эксплуатации нет.
Надежность определяется достоверностью исходных данных.
```

или любой подобный бред. Нормальные люди все равно такие части работы не читают.

Comment: Хм, я так и хотел написать) Мне сказали типа роспиши... вот я немного в ступоре, а что бы про диспетчер написать бы такого)